# Express server unable to proxy to my React project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, proxy

I have an issue, my server is giving me an error that it is unable to proxy from localhost:8080 to localhost:3000 on my local machine, it also showed a Http parse error together.

I am trying to run a React and Express project and it worked when I used cloud9 to run it.

Comment: React and express are running on a different port?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, this is actually my first time of asking a question

Comment: @oxy_js yes they are